# How do I solve given two variable equation with different modulus?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Given the integer of value of $Z$ and two equations:

$k_1 x + C = Z{\mod{y}}$

$k_2 y + C = Z{\mod{x}}$

where x and y are variables to find, and $k_1$, $k_2$, and $C$ are unknown constants.

In other words, I wish to solve the equation: $k_1x - k_2y = Z{\mod{x}} - Z{\mod{y}}$

Or possibly find a complete relationship between $x$ and $y$ to satisfy the above equation.

Note: $y = ix$ (i = any integer) always satisfies the equation. But it is not a complete solution.

Comment: are you asking hpw to solve $x\equiv (Z-C)k_1^{-1} \pmod y$ and $y\equiv (Z-C)k_2^{-1}\pmod x$ ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee $(Z(\mod{x}))\mod{y} = (Z(\mod{y})\mod{x})$